# Prevent React from re-render on state change during render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React re-render a component everytime a State change ([Doc - re-renders-when-state-updates](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/render-and-commit#re-renders-when-state-updates))

However, I want to make several State edition during a render, before a new render is commited. 
In my case, my State is a big dictionnary. This dict is often edited, so I use a reducer in order to be make quick and small edits :

```
concatDict = (dictA, dictB) => {...dictA, ...dictB}

const [MyDict, updateMyDict] = useReducer(concatDict, {});

updateMyDict({a: 2})
updateMyDict({b: 4, c: 3})
```

That would commit several re-render before I finished updating my State. It isn't that bad anyway, but is there a way to prevent it ?

Note : useMemo is probably what I need, but i'm not sure yet (reading the doc and testing on my own)

Comment: If there is no `async` code involved, then the updates are batched and will only trigger a single re-render after all updates have been run.

Comment: Adding up to @GabrielePetrioli comment, read [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching) for reference.